# Growing last row of an array implemented in array of pointer to arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a dynamically-allocated two-dimensional data structure with capacity of 25 strings, each with a length up to 50. How can I grow the last row of t, an array of pointer to arrays, so it has room for a string of length 200 instead of 50? I want it to also preserve the contents of the string.

This is how I have dynamically allocated t, the two-dimensional array structure:

```
char **t;
t = (char **) malloc (25 * sizeof(char));

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  t[i] = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
```

Can I access the last row with `t[24]`? How do I actually change the length of the string to 200 instead of 50?

So far, I have tried `t[24] = (char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));` but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: `25 * sizeof(char)` is too small, only 25 bytes.  Suggest `sizeof *t * 25` to allocate 25 pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `realloc()` to change the size of an existing allocation. If you use `malloc()` as you did, you lose the original contents of the array, and also lose the pointer to it so you can't free the memory.

```
char *temp = realloc(t[24], 200 * sizeof(char));
if (temp) {
    t[24] = temp;
}
```